# In sml, why it produce Error: syntax error: deleting IN IF

Tags: emacs, sml

I'm making a function to determine whether a tree is balanced or not.

```
fun balanced(tree) =
  let 
    fun size tree =
      case tree of
           Lf => 0
         | Br(xs,ys,zs) => 1 + size ys + size zs
    fun depth tree =
      case tree of
           Lf => 0
         | Br(xs,ys,zs) =>
            let val l_count = 1 + depth ys
                val r_count = 1+ depth zs
            in
              if l_count > r_count then l_count else r_count
            end
  in
    if size(ys) = size(zs) andalso depth(ys) = depth(zs) then true
    else if tree=Lf then true
    else false
  end;
```

But it produces these errors:

```
stdIn:829.18-829.20 Error: unbound variable or constructor: zs
stdIn:829.9-829.11 Error: unbound variable or constructor: ys
stdIn:829.48-829.50 Error: unbound variable or constructor: zs
stdIn:829.36-829.38 Error: unbound variable or constructor: ys
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've removed the `emacs` tag and reformatted your code so that it highlights properly in StackOverflow's markdown. I've made some minor adjustments to the indentation of your code to make it more readable.

Comment: You probably want to use pattern matching on `tree` (like in `size` and `depth`) in your main function.

Answer (score 2):

Between `in` and `end`

```
  in
    if size(ys) = size(zs) andalso depth(ys) = depth(zs) then true
    else if tree=Lf then true
    else false
  end;
```

you use `ys` and `zs` that you never define before. The `ys` and `zs` you have in `depth` and `size` functions are local to these functions and not visible to `balanced`.

Comment: so how can i make 'visible'?

Comment: @이이도경 declare it between `let` and `in` or have a `case tree of` between `in` and `end`. See `melpomene`'s comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the datatype that this function operates on. I assume it looks like this:

```
datatype 'a binary_tree = Lf | Br of 'a * 'a binary_tree * 'a binary_tree
```

You get the unbound variable errors because the code

```
if size(ys) = size(zs) andalso ...
```

does not have such variables in its scope. Those variables are only available in the scope of your helper functions. Here's some hints:

1. Don't name your variables `xs`, `ys` and `zs` when `xs` is in fact the value residing in the branch and `ys` and `zs` are in fact the left and right sub-trees of the branch. Better names could be `x` (or `_` if you don't use it), `left` and `right`.
2. Use `Int.max (x, y)` instead of `if x > y then x else y`.

   Similarly, `if foo then true else false` is equivalent to just `foo`.

   So you don't need if-then-else in the body of `balanced`.
3. Perform the pattern match directly in the function argument.
4. It isn't necessary to know the number of elements in a sub-tree (`size`) to determine if it's balanced. It's only necessary to know the tree's height/depth (`depth`).
5. Move the helper functions out of this function.

   They're useful in their own right.

   ```
   fun size Lf = 0
     | size (Br (_, left, right)) = 1 + size left + size right

   fun depth Lf = 0
     | depth (Br (_, left, right)) = 1 + Int.max (depth left, depth right)
   ```
6. Write `balanced` in a [declarative way](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-determine-if-a-binary-tree-is-balanced/): An empty tree (`Lf`) is trivially balanced. A non-empty tree (`Br ...`) is balanced if the left sub-tree is balanced, the right sub-tree is balanced, and the difference of the depth of the left and the right sub-tree is not more than 1.

   ```
   fun balanced Lf = true
     | balanced (Br (_, left, right)) =
         balanced left andalso
         balanced right andalso
         ...the 'abs'(olute) difference of 'depth left' and 'depth right' is not more than 1...
   ```
7. This solution traverses the tree quite a lot: First with `balanced` and *then* with `depth`. You can write a solution to this exercise that only traverses the tree once by returning a tuple `(is_subtree_balanced, subtree_height)`.

   ```
   fun balanced_helper Lf = (true, 0)
     | balanced_helper (Br (_, left, right)) =
       let val (is_left_balanced, left_height) = balanced_helper left
       in ...we can stop here if the left sub-tree isn't balanced...
          let val (is_right_balanced, right_height) = balanced_helper right
          in ...we can stop here if the right sub-tree isn't balanced...
             ...otherwise: (true, 1 + Int.max(left_height, right_height))...
          end
        end

   fun balanced tree = #1 (balanced_helper tree)
   ```

Comment: thank you for your help then how can i perform the pattern match directly in the function argument(number 3 in your reply)? i am not very familiar with sml :(

Comment: I cannot understant 7 what is otherwise part? also i can follow up the process...

Comment: I've shown how you can pattern match without using case-of three places. Don't worry about bullet (7) until you've solved the problem in a simple way first.